# Caused by: org.gradle.api.InvalidUserCodeException: Using dependency catalogs requires the activation of the matching feature preview

Tags: gradle

When I was trying to use the Catalog feature in Gradle 7.0
https://docs.gradle.org/7.0.2/userguide/platforms.html#sub:central-declaration-of-dependencies

as below into `setting.gradle`

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    // Some other codes

    versionCatalogs {
        libs {
            alias('androidx-core').to('androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0')
            alias('androidx-appcompat').to('androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1')
            alias('androidx-constrainlayout').to('androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.0')
            alias('android-material').to('com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0')
        }
    }
}
```

When I perform gradle sync, it errors out stating

```
Caused by: org.gradle.api.InvalidUserCodeException: Using dependency catalogs requires the activation of the matching feature preview.
```

I check https://docs.gradle.org/7.0.2/userguide/platforms.html#sub:central-declaration-of-dependencies, and found it states

```
Central declaration of dependencies is an incubating feature. It requires the activation of the VERSION_CATALOGS feature preview.
```

And in https://docs.gradle.org/7.0.2/userguide/feature_lifecycle.html#feature_preview it states

```
The feature preview API allows certain incubating features to be activated by adding enableFeaturePreview('FEATURE') in your settings file. Individual preview features will be announced in release notes.
```

I tried adding `enableFeaturePreview('FEATURE')` in `settings.gradle`, but don't seems to work. Where should I place `enableFeaturePreview('FEATURE')`?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Looks like I need to replace the `FEATURE` to the actual feature's name. i.e.

```
enableFeaturePreview("VERSION_CATALOGS")
```

I just put it in the first line of `settings.gradle` file, that will do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, it works when I added `enableFeaturePreview("VERSION_CATALOGS")` line in the **last line** of `settings.gradle (project-name)` file.

Files are

**settings.gradle (project-name)**

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
rootProject.name = "project-name"
include ':app'
enableFeaturePreview("VERSION_CATALOGS")
```

and **build.gradle (project-name)**

```
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.android.application) apply(false)
    alias(libs.plugins.android.library) apply(false)
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlin.android) apply(false)
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```